# Running a shell command on local files with Docker Alpine

Tags: shell, docker, busybox, alpine-linux

I have directories full of files with extension `.dic`, and I need to rename them (recursively) to have the extension `.dcm`. BUT, I need to do this by running a Docker with volume mounted on the local files.

So, I pulled the Alpine Docker image and started to play with it. As there isn't the `rename` command in the Alpine image, I use `find`, `mv` and `sed`:

1) Run a container from the Alpine image, mount my local directory in `/tmp`, and start a shell session in the container:

```
docker run -ti -v `pwd`:/tmp alpine /bin/sh
```

2) Inside the container, run the renaming command:

```
find /tmp -name '*.dic' | while read filename; do mv ${filename} $(echo ${filename} | sed -e 's/\.dic$/\.dcm/'); done
```

This is working fine, but what I really need to do is launch the container, run the command, and exit. So I tried:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/tmp alpine /bin/sh -c "find /tmp -name '*.dic' | while read filename; do mv ${filename} $(echo ${filename} | sed -e 's/\.dic$/\.dcm/'); done"
```

But it is not working, the files are not renamed, and the output is:

```
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-05-30 10:45:57 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: mv [-fin] SOURCE DEST
or: mv [-fin] SOURCE... DIRECTORY

Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY

    -f  Don't prompt before overwriting
    -i  Interactive, prompt before overwrite
    -n  Don't overwrite an existing file
```

... repeated once for each file to rename found.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because the use of double quotes to wrap the string means the variables (e.g. `${filename}`) are interpolated *outside* of the Alpine shell. What you really want is to pass the string into the container inside single-quotes, so the interpolation happens within the container.

The following works to do the nested rename by using a single-quoted string, with double-quoted strings inside it (the opposite of what the question has):

```
docker run -v pwd:/tmp alpine /bin/sh -c 'find /tmp -name "*.dic" | while read filename; do mv ${filename} $(echo ${filename} | sed -e "s/\.dic$/\.dcm/"); done'
```

However, although this works, it's not the perfect solution. Another approach which retains the use of single-quotes within the executed command would be to wrap single quotes in double quotes and glue that into the strings, e.g. "'"'s/find/replace/g'"'". Whether the myriad extra quotes and lower legibility is worth it is a question for the reader. That would look something like this:

```
docker run -v pwd:/tmp alpine /bin/sh -c 'find /tmp -name '"'"'*.dic'"'"' | while read filename; do mv ${filename} $(echo ${filename} | sed -e '"'"'s/\.dic$/\.dcm/'"'"'); done'
```

TBH I generally get around this sort of wrangling by dropping the command into a script file and including that in the mount, as the script can be more easily shared/version controlled then.

Answer (score 1):

sadly aplpine does not have rename, plus complicated* bash commands over docker cli is a weird animal

took me few tries... but was good mental break :)
try this:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/tmp  alpine /bin/sh -c "find /tmp -name '*.dic' -exec sh -c 'mv $"0" $"{0%.dic}".dcm'  {} \;"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution works. But I selected @spikeheap 's answer because it made me understand what I did wrong with single/double quotes.

Comment: @scandel no problem, glad i could help